# UserID from AuthenticationStateProvider appears empty

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using AspNetCore Identity and trying to get the UserID of the currently logged in user using AuthenticationStateProvider. I am logging to the console the output however, the username outputs fine but the ID appears empty. The ID field is not empty in the db table. When printing all the claims the ***subs*** field seems to be the correct ID. Am I incorrectly retrieving the ID? The approach to retrieve the ID was suggested from another post I found; code is shown below. How might I retrieve the *sub* value which is the userID, in my page using AuthenticationStateProvider? Thanks in advance.

### Retrieving UserID

```
 var user = (await ASP.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
 var UserStringId = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type.Equals(user.Identity.Name))?.Value;
```

### Browser console output

```
USER ID: blazor.webassembly.js:1 
NAME: user4@gmail.com
```

### Sub is correct ID when looping through Claims

```
    var user = (await ASP.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
    var item = user.Claims;

    foreach(var x in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

### Browser console output

```
s_hash: EQ_bVJS8n32qtUam0wZ1MA
sid: 2E6B597CC9644CFEFDD627532B761F02
sub: 5685a830-cb82-4b60-b459-c0852cc74563 // trying to retrieve this ID
//...
preferred_username: user4@gmail.com
name: user4@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The UserID still appears as empty when printing it to the browser console.